# Address out of range MIPS Assembly

Tags: mips32

I was wondering if anyone could please help me with debugging an address out of range error (denoted by comment in asm file) - I'm trying to write a simple assembly program targeting MIPS for the following code:

```
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

void main() {
    struct point p2;
    p2.x = 1;
    print_i(p2.x);   
}
```

The assembly file produced was:

```
.data
.text
j main
main: 
move $fp $sp      #initialize fp to sp
addi $sp, $sp, -8 #allocate space for struct with 2 int fields
lw $t0, -8($fp)   #load data at address for first field of p2 into $t0
sw $t0, 0($t9)    #Out of Range error occurs here
li $t8, 1
sw $t8, ($t9)
li    $v0, 1
lw $t0, -8($fp)
sw $t0, 0($t9)
add $a0, $t9, $zero
syscall
li    $v0, 10
syscall
```

I think I'm loading data from the wrong address, but I've tried running the assembly with -4($fp) as well and I'm not sure what other address I should be using to get the location of field x for p2. I know this may be super obvious, but I'm just starting to learn how assembly works and I've been stuck on this for a while. Any help debugging or explanations of what my program is doing here would be super appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: I don't see where you initialize the `$t9` register here? I think your issue is a mere typo since you dereference an un-initialized register